# android background color changing

Tags: android, multithreading

I am looking to change my color of my background for a second after a button has been pressed to confirm if the correct button was clicked. Afterwords, I want to switch the color back to black, but when I use Thread.sleep() it doesn't change the color before or after the thread sleep. Any other suggestions?

```
background.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
thread.sleep(1000);
background.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: What is the object named background?

Comment: Use CountDownTimer for this task. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Why not just use background.postDelayed()?

Comment: background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);

Answer (score -1):

Modify your code like this:

```
background.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
background.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: This didn't seem to get the color change but still lets me keep clicking unlike before when I didn't declare a new thread. I should probably give some more details though to help. Currently, this code is inside of a setOnClickListener, that will change the background color to Green for one second if the correct button is pushed and Red if the wrong button is pushed. When I tried it with thread.run() instead of thread.start() it infinite looped. The action I am getting with this code inserted is just the screen remaining black.